# Launching EPIserver website from Visual Studio takes at least 5 minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express, episerver

I do not know if this is a Visual Studio, ASP.Net-MVC, IIS Express or EPIserver issue.

The problem is that in Visual Studio, when I click on what looks like a play icon, it takes at least 5 minutes until my local EPIserver development website loads in the browser.

I have tried selecting different browsers from within Visual Studio: Firefox, Chrome, MS Edge.

We have also tested this on 2 identical laptops, and 2 identical desktops. All running the latest Windows 10.

What happens is that about 4-5 seconds after I click on play, a browser instance will be launched. This is pointing to localhost. It then takes at least 5 minutes for the website to start loading in the browser.

This is making it really hard to work efficiently.

I would be very thankful for any tips on what to try, what to check, etc..

I am a relatively new users when it comes to all of the above mentioned components, so I would be very thankful for step by step tips on what to check/test.

Answer (score 3):

Enable **log4net** logging (usually config file called `EPiServerLog.config` in the site root) using a relevant appender with `debug`-level logging.

The logs can probably show you what happens after the site has started. I have seen examples where poor implementations have, for example, iterated all content on a site on startup, causing a ton of database traffic as the cache is populated. Needless to say that takes *a long time*. :)

If the logs don't give anything away, I would suggest attaching the VS debugger to do some basic profiling on startup.

[Example on configuring **log4net**](https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/log4net-messages-in-real-time-with-debugview/), albeit an old post.